# iOS Amplify: Access schema.graphql in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, aws-amplify

The backend developer designed and added Amplify qraphql schema file `schema.graphql` to the project. I dragged the schema.graphql file to the project like in this example:

[image]

Now, I just want to access the query methods in Swift.

I can query generally like this:

```
Amplify.API.query(request: .list(Device.self)){ event in
}
```

But not like this:

```
Amplify.API.query(request: .getDeviceByKitId(kitId: 1)){ event in }
```

I get errors like:

> Type 'GraphQLRequest<_>' has no member 'getDeviceByKitId'

The question is how to access or convert query and mutation methods in `schema.graphql` into Swift?